# Twitter login page comes up even though user denies to give access to Twitter from App

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, authentication

When I am trying to login to my App in iOS 11 using Twitter, sometimes I am getting an alertview-style popup saying “ wants to open twitter”, with the options "cancel" and "open". If I tap on "open", it is the normal login flow for twitter.

However, if I tap on cancel, then what I want is for the whole login attempt to be cancelled. Instead, the app redirects me to the webview which opens twitter login page and again I need to cancel that dismiss the page saying “Error during login”. Could anyone able to simulate it?

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTV1R.jpg][1]]

Comment: Could you paste your code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be related to a known issue that Twitter is trying to fix? See https://twittercommunity.com/t/bug-twitter-kit-ios-3-0-4-login-sometimes-fails-to-redirect-back-to-host-app/89618/24